# How to resolve ICE03: String overflow in WiX?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

In my installer a feature tree control in the **maintenance dialog** publishes two events that sets a property named `DisableInstallBtn` to 0 or 1, respectively. And `DisableInstallBtn` is used by the condition of enable/disable action of `Install` button. It behaves like this: **If all the features are 'deselected' then the `Install` button becomes disabled.**

So, each event(Publish element) has a condition to be published. For example, the event that sets `DisableInstallBtn` to 1 has a condition like this: `<![CDATA[(!Feature1=2 OR &Feature1=2) AND ... AND (!FeatureN=2 OR &FeatureN=2)]]>`(If you don't understand the syntax of this condition you can check http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax)

The problem is this condition string is too long so that I get String overflow warning when I compile .wxs file. Is there any way to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WiX's built-in `CustomizeDlg` (located under src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib if you have the source code) already has the functionality you're looking for in its next button. Just subscribe to the `SelectionNoItems` event.

```
<Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton">
    <Subscribe Event="SelectionNoItems" Attribute="Enabled" />
</Control>
```

The `SelectionTree` control has a lot of events associated with it. You can view them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT**

It seems that I've misunderstood the documentation. The `SelectionNoItems` only fires when the selection tree has no nodes, not when the current selection has no nodes.

Starting with Windows Installer 3.0, the selection tree publishes a `DoAction` event, which fires when there's a change in your selection tree.

You can then check your feature selection in your custom action and set the `Control.Attributes` column of your next button. You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a list of attributes and their values (enabled is equal to 2).

Otherwise, you can always do your validation on clicking next.

Comment: Umm.. it seems that SelectionNoItems event is only published when there is *no nodes* in selection tree(empty tree), not no selected items in the tree. Isn't it right?

Comment: @sky You're right. Sorry about that. I've updated my post with another solution.